# How do I contribute to a git repository between 2 different places without merge conflicts

Tags: git, github

I am the sole developer on a project.
As an example, say I have the following scenario:

Office A - make changes to code, **commit** then **push**

Office B - try to **pull** changes, but if any changes made it complains. I want to forget any changes made and get the latest version.

Basically I am switching between offices A & B, and each time I want to commit changes to the remote repository, and then get those changes again from the next office.  Git will complain as there might be some minor changes in the working copy.  I've been using **git reset --hard** followed by a **pull**, but this doesn't feel right somehow. I've looked at **stash** too but that seems to save changes somewhere for use at a later time.

The number of commands for git seems bewildering!

Comment: When you pull and "it complains", what is the message you get from Git?

Comment: If you really do want to throw away all your changes, I don't see anything wrong with using git reset --hard. If you're not sure, then git stash is exacatly what you need. You don't have to ever use what you stashed away and it's easy to clean up: git stash clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (and git) are doing it exactly as you should. You're not using git incorrectly; it's intended to be able to push and pull from different places just like this.

**The reason git complains to you**, is because it's required by the changeset model: Suppose on machine A, you made a commit with hash "abcdef". In order to be able to share changesets between the repositories, like you want to do, commit "abcdef" must be *exactly* the same, everywhere. On machine B, when you pull that commit into your local changes, it might put that commit into the history in some particular place, but it cannot *mix* that commit with your local changes. Doing so would produce commit "3dea12", which is entirely different.

Git could try to mix your changes on the fly, like subversion does. Consider, though, if you had committed six times: now you have to merge six times, once for each (indivisible) commit applied on the other machine. Subversion gets around this by summarizing the changes in an all-in-all blob of a diff, which it then tries to put on top of your local changes. It works sometimes, but some of the merging gets kinda screwy and it *doesn't* let you keep the neat, changesets-never-change history that git offers.

**To solve your problem**, here's your pull strategy on machine B:

```
$ git stash       # Set your uncommitted changes aside for a moment
$ git pull        # Pull in the new changes
                  # <resolve conflicts, if they happen>
$ git stash pop   # Bring back your uncommitted changes, fixing ambiguous
                  #     merge pieces as necessary.
```

Basically, this is the, "don't worry, `git stash` isn't scary," strategy. :)

I think it's important to notice that *you will have to merge*. Good development practices, keeping changes small and so on might make merges happen less often, but you will still have to merge sometimes.

By the way, **you *want* git to complain.** If your working copy is clean (no stashes needed), you're mixing one history with another. Git will find the spots where you need to merge and ask you what to do. It's a pretty clear process. If it has to conflate those spots with local changes *as well*, the history would get very confusing. That would essentially be merging things from the past with things from "the future", which in this case is your uncommitted work (that will probably change!).

In light of that, here's your other option:

```
$ git commit -m "..."    # Commit your local changes, making them part of history.
$ git pull               # Clean working copy! (maybe merging required)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get into the habit of committing often. Basically, every step you do can result in a commit. These aren't expensive in git but can make your life much easier as the typically working granularity is on the commit level. You shopuld also do this to experiments and tests, you never know when these code parts become important :)

Once you start to commit early and often, you should start to get into the habit of using topic branches. In difference to e.g. SVN, branches are also cheap. a branch is basically just a pointer to a commit, the HEAD of the branch, so it is not much different from a tag. Using branches is in the heart of git and the quest to find a usage model of git for you basically resolves around finding a branching model that suits you and our workflow.

So you should start to use separate branches for every feature you develop. Once it is finished, you can merge the branch back into mainline/master/whatever and just delete the branch. The upside of this approach is that you can develop your features independently from each other and don't need to [Experience Bij](http://vimeo.com/11040425) prematurely.

Now if you have committed everything and put stuff into neat branches, you can push all the branches up to the server. As you don't have any uncommitted changes in your local repositories and you have always worked on top of the existing commits, you shouldn't have any merge conflicts, as the branches are only fast-forwarded.

Comment: While the content of your post is mostly sound, it is entirely unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: I mean, all these things are good, but they don't really address the problem here.

Comment: @Paul: Well, no. The OP wrote that he has (merge) conflicts when moving between offices, an issue which can entirely be resolved with using a better workflow. His proposed workarounds with either `stash` or `reset` are only needed when this workflow is not observed but when he is more sloppy. Especially when using topic branches, stashing can be avoided almost completely. Also rewriting history is very dangerous as it is to throw uncommitted changes away if you are not very careful. One day, you are going to reset important changes by accident and are screwed...

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing when managing development from my primary workstation and when I go mobile on my laptop. On occasion I'll have something on the laptop that I was working on that didn't get committed so there are conflicts when I try to pull from the main repo. I will do a `git diff` to see what it was I was working on and then decide if I need to `stash` or `reset` those changes.